# Can a function return a string in c?

Tags: c, function, return

Question is pretty much self-explainable, but I will add an example just to clarify it.

For example, we have this function:

```
    char abc(void)
    {
      code...
      code...
      return a;
    }
```

This function will return char a to abc, but can a function return a whole string, without using pointers, file I/O and such things?

Comment: In C, a string _is_ normally a pointer because it's a `char` array (aka `char*` or `char[]`).

Comment: A string is a char pointer, this is how C represents strings there is no way to avoid this fact.

Comment: use struct (as wrapper).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97688/discussion-on-question-by-leon000-can-a-function-return-a-string-in-c).

Comment: http://ideone.com/8kCITY

Answer (score 1):

C strings are arrays of `char`, terminated by a `char` with value `0`.  C functions cannot return arrays themselves, including strings, nor, indeed, can arrays be passed as arguments.  Passing and / or returning pointers is C's alternative to passing and / or returning arrays.  To a large extent you don't even need to do anything special to pass or return pointers in place of arrays.

Because it is somewhat cumbersome to speak precisely about these things, the pointer / array distinction is often left out of discussion and even documentation.  One often refers to a `char *` *as* a string, when in fact the string is the array whose first element is pointed to.  This does present the possibility of confusion, however, as is evident in the question and the associated comments.

Comment: So basically, you can't return strings with normal return in a function, but you must use pointers, if I understood what you meant?

Comment: @leon000: Exactly. Avoiding pointer in C is like not drinking liquids: You will not get far. If you don't like pointers, C is definitively the wrong language.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much guys, I guess I must then either work around pointers or go read up on pointers as I'm not really a master of pointers and I've just started learning them. Just saw your edit, I'm not really avoiding pointers, I'm just let's say postponing them, as I've not yet really learnt them to their full extent.